# Getting Exception: "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Java.CompileFile.doCompilation(CompileFile.java:48)
at GUI.CompilerForm.compileBtnActionPerformed(CompilerForm.java:225)
at GUI.CompilerForm.access$400(CompilerForm.java:23)
............
```

I no the error is at line 48 in CompileFile.java, it is saying that the array in NULL and i dont know why because that is where i am adding strings to it!

```
String[] compile;
int numberOfErrors = 0;
.
.
.
 for (Diagnostic diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()) {                
            String errors = diagnostic.getKind().toString()+" on line  "+ diagnostic.getLineNumber() +"\nIn file:  \n"+ diagnostic.toString();
            compile[numberOfErrors] = errors;
            numberOfErrors++;
        }
```

I have tried `System.out.println(errors);` straight after i set it and it is working fine so i really dont know what is going on!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide more information on how you initialise the array compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've declared a variable called `compile`, but you haven't shown anywhere that it's given a value. Assuming it's an instance variable, its value will default to `null`. You need to initialize it with:

```
compile = new String[someSize];
```

where `someSize` is "big enough".

Alternatively, and preferrably, you could use a list:

```
// TODO: Rename variable to something more sensible
private final List<String> compile = new ArrayList<String>();
```

then...

```
compile.add(errors);
```

Then you can probably get rid of `numberOfErrors` too, as that would just be `compile.size()` presumably.

Answer (score 1):

From the code snap you are showing, it seems you did not initialize `compile`, so it is initialized to `null` as default.

You should explicitly create a `String[]` and assign it to `compile`:

```
compile = new String[MY_SIZE];
```

If you are trying to append errors, you might want to consider using a [dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) - which is an [`ArrayList<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) in java for it, and append elements, using [`ArrayList.add(element)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you haven't initialized the array (properly)

```
String[] compiled = new String[size];
```

or you haven't set a proper size of the array

If you **are unable to predict how many items**  there will be in the array. Use **lists** (eg ArrayList) instead

```
 List<String> compiled = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Arraylists have **no size limit.**

To add items

```
 compiled.add(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't initialized your array.

Try something like this :

```
compile = new String[numberOfErrors];
```

And then store the errors in the array.